# Java-script, Google chrome extension: Undefined class variable, in method referenced by callback

Tags: javascript, oop, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make Google Chrome extension.

For the beginning, I want to create javascript class, that represents the active browser tab and let me work with that HTML source. It should be used like this:

```
var currentTab = new CurrentTab();

currentTab.requestHtml(function(html){
    // `html` contents active tab HTML
});
```

I googled, and I found that HTML of active tab can't be getted directly to extension's popup. But I can pass my own javascript to tab, that respons his HTML to my extension through `chrome.extension.sendRequest()`. So, my `CurrentTab` class look like this:

```
var CurrentTab = function(){
    this.listeners = {
        'requestHtml': {}
    };

    chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(this._processListener);
};
CurrentTab.prototype = {
    requestHtml: function(callback){
        var actionKey = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10000);  // get random identifier for this callback

        this.listeners['requestHtml'][actionKey] = callback;

        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { 
            code: 'console.log("SendContent.js");'
                + 'chrome.extension.sendRequest({'
                + '     action: "' + actionKey + '",'
                + '     host: document.location.hostname,'
                + '     content: document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].outerHTML'
                + '}, function(response){});'
        });
    },

    _processListener: function(request, sender, sendResponse){
        /*25.*/console.log(this.listeners);  // `this.listeners` is 'undefined' ???
        if (this.listeners['requestHtml'][request.action]) {
            this.listeners['requestHtml'][request.action](request.content);
            delete this.listeners['requestHtml'][request.action];
        }
    }
};
```

The problem is at line 25 of this class. Though the `_processListener` method is part of `CurrentTab` class, variable `this.listeners` is undefined here, when this method is called via callback.

Please, how can I fix this and why it is happening? Thanks.

Comment: I figure out, that this is proplem of pure javascript. This 10-line code example also not working as I expected: http://jsfiddle.net/NmLxm/1/. But if I call manually `bf.processListener()`, it works fine. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lock the context of the function using [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
var CurrentTab = function(){
    ...

    chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(this._processListener.bind(this));
};
```